# How does C2 work on the ATMega328P?

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, hardware

What is the purpose of C2 on this schematic below?

How does it work when the microcontroller is being programmed?

[image]

Comment: what happens to DTR when the microcontroller is being programmed?

Comment: If SJ1 is connected, and when DTR go from HIGH to LOW, what do you think will happen on the RESET pin?  Also read [this](https://www.electrical4u.com/discharging-a-capacitor/).